# Cannot stop Tomcat6 installed via Macports in Mac OS X 10.7.3

Tags: macos, tomcat, macports, myeclipse

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3. I installed tomcat6 via macports 2.0.4. I put the tomcat6 location in myeclipse for spring 10 server configuration. Everything was fine so far.

Then I tried to start it in myeclipse. It could not start, saying something like 8080 port is already in use.

Then I went to terminal.

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

4 process showed up. It seemed tomcat6 started automatically after the installation. Then I tried to stop it with

```
sudo tomcatctl stop
```

Here came the problem. No matter how I tried, it always says

```
Stopping Tomcat...(pid ****)............... giving up.
```

I tried to kill the process but it kept starting tomcat again right after the kill.

How do I stop it and let myeclipse take over it? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Milo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing `sudo port unload tomcat6`

This command replaced interacting with `launchctl` yourself, but im unsure if it supports a `-w` switch which would typically remove the launch daemon were it used with `launchctl unload` meaning you wouldnt run into the magic restart problem.